# Laravel eloquent whereNotExists with join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to rewrite this pseudo query using Eloquent?

```
select * from a1, b1
where a1.id=b1.a_id
and not exists (select 1 from a1, b1, c1 where a1.id=b1.a_id and b1.id=c1.b_id)
```

I've tried the following approach, but couldn't figure out how to pass multiple tables in closure

```
A1_Model::where('a1.is_active', 1)
->join('b1', 'b1.a_id', '=', 'a1.id')
->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                ->from('a1') // how can I pass two tables here? Array doesn't work
                ->whereRaw('');
        })
```

Comment: Why not simply use join like in table above?

Comment: I recommend using `whereColumn` instead of `whereRaw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two approaches you could use:

```
A1_Model::where('a1.is_active', 1)
->join('b1', 'b1.a_id', '=', 'a1.id')
->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                ->from('a1')
                ->join('b1', 'b1.a_id', '=', 'a1.id')
                ->join('c1', 'c1.b_id', '=', 'b1.id')
                ->whereRaw('');
        });
```

You can also use `DB::table` and `DB::raw` to achieve the same result.

```
DB::table(DB::raw('a1', 'b1', 'c1')); //same effect as select from a1, b1, c1
```

Comment: This is useful, let me give it a try

Answer (score 1):

try this one for more http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
A1_Model::where('a1.is_active', 1)
->join('b1', 'b1.a_id', '=', 'a1.id')
 ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($a1){
        $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
            ->from($a1)
            ->whereRaw('');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Chibueze Opata suggested better solution

---

I guess there is no other way of doing this except using select + db::raw. Here is the actual query

```
IndicatorModel::where('indicators.is_active', 1)
        ->where('f.is_active', 1)
        ->where('f.logframe_type_id', 1)
        ->whereIn('f.level_id', [1,2])
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($countryId) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw('1 from indicator_mapping m2, indicators i2, logframes f2
                   where m2.src_indicator_id=i2.id and i2.logframe_id=f2.id and i2.is_active=1
                   and m2.mapped_indicator_id=indicators.id and f2.country_id=' . $countryId));
        })
        ->join('logframes as f', 'f.id', '=', 'indicators.logframe_id')
        ->select('f.id')
        ->groupBy('f.id')
        ->orderBy('f.level_id')
        ->get();
```